# Simulink Matlab Function Block 'Size mismatch' Error

Tags: matlab, size, simulink, matlab-coder

I am using a Matlab function block in a Simulink model. The Input is a 1x32 binary stream and the Output y is an integer between 0 and 15. I have 2 variables defined within this function called chip=zeros(17,32) and reconst_op=zeros(1,32). My Problem is that when I compare these two variables in an if condition as follows:

function y = De_Spreading_Mod(input)

1. if all(reconst_op==chip(1,:)) .. do something..

OR 2. if all(reconst_op(1,:)==chip(1,:))

Both the above conditions cause Matlab throw an error as follows:

for case 1, Size mismatch (size [:? x 32] ~= size [1 x 32]). Mismatched varying and fixed sizes indicate a probable run-time error. If this diagnostic is incorrect, use indexing to explicitly make the varying size fixed.

for case 2, MATLAB Function Interface Error: Simulation stopped due to out of bounds error. Runtime Error: Attempted to access 1 element of data reconst_chip_op whose runtime size is 0.

However, if I run the same Piece of code in a separate m file, it works as expected but only in the Simulink embedded matlab function block, it is an issue.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How do you get the variable reconst_op? Based on the errors it does not look like it is a fixed size of 1x32.

Comment: I declare and initialize it as follows: reconst_chip_op=Zeros(1,32) and assign the following: reconst_chip_op=chip_seq(index,:); The Problem I have noticed is that in the first iteration, the size is 1x32 but in the next Iteration, the size becomes 0x32 though I am not doing that anywhere.

Comment: Where do you get index from? Can that become empty?

Comment: I realised that this issue was due to ignoring a null check . Thanks for the help anyway.